# Why do Stack Exchange sites not have 2 factor authentication?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In my personal opinion, 2-factor authentication is an important feature that Stack Exchange sites should have yet they lack it.

I was contemplating writing a post of some importance but I'm being held back by the fact that 1-factor authentication isn't very secure.

Is this feature going to be implemented anytime soon?

Comment: *"I was contemplating writing a post of some importance  but I'm being held back by the fact that 1-factor authentication isn't very secure."* I'm confused as to why the lack of 2FA would stop you; all content here is public so as soon as you've submitted the post *anyone* can view and edit it.

Comment: @Larnu What does "public" has to do with account security?

Comment: What does 2FA have to do with making an "important" post? No posts on [so] are more important than others, so I'm trying to understand why you can't make the post you want to due to a lack of 2FA. Why is the lack of 2FA "holding you back" from making an "important" post?

Comment: uhmm, hackers maybe?

Comment: A "hacker" could just create a new account and deface your post, so I don't see the problem still on why the lack of 2FA is stopping you make an "important" post. Why is it so important?

Comment: What would hackers do with your important post? Delete it - it can be undeleted. Edit it - it can be reverted. Also, how often really do hackers steal SO accounts to do whatever the nefarious deed you think they do with posts?

Comment: A hacker couldn't really get away with doing a lot of damage, really...since everything has an audit trail, the best that they could do is inconvenience a Stack Overflow developer for a day while they clean up the mess.  Then you (the owner of the account) would still bear the brunt of the suspension for keeping ["correct horse battery staple"](https://xkcd.com/936/) as your password.

Comment: @Larnu heck, you don't even need an account to edit posts. Anonymous users can also make suggested edits.

Comment: @VLAZ exactly, which makes me even more confused as to what the op is concerned about.

Comment: "*I was contemplating writing a post of some importance*", Okay..., but hum, you are a bit early (2 weeks) for the 2023 April Fools jokes, I would think...

Comment: @chivracq why do you think it's a joke?

Comment: Maybe because you seem to be *really* concerned about something but are only giving rather... strange justifications for being concerned about it? I don't really see a problem for requesting stack add a 2fa option, but not because I'm concerned someone will... do something... with an important post i'm considering posting... given anything someone with access to your account can do to that post anyone else in the community can do as well.

Comment: Well @OP, you have 4k-Rep, you should know a bit how the Site works, your "*post of some importance*" sounds like an April Fools joke..., or a prank...

Comment: *If* you took the time to explain why the lack of of 2FA is stopping you from posting something "important", and why that post is important, some users might not think it's a joke, @machine_1 .

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318807/332043

Comment: There are plenty of duplicates. Here is [one from 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355251/why-not-add-optional-simple-totp-2fa). [A list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=2FA).

Comment: "I was contemplating writing a post of some importance but I'm being held back by the fact that 1-factor authentication isn't very secure." - It's currently implanted.  My account is linked to my Google Account, which is secured with 2FA, thus my Stack Exchange community accounts are secured with 2FA.

Comment: What **precisely** is your threat model here?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i didn't give it a lot of thought but 2FA gives additional security

Comment: The most use a "hacker" could have for other people's accounts is to use them for spamming purposes. Most anti-spammer measures that are in place at sign up are defeated when existing accounts are breached. A moot point though, as Makoto points out most methods of signing in support 2FA on their own.

Comment: People with the argument that "hackers wouldn't cause much damage" completely miss the point. That argument is along the exact same lines as "increased surveillance is fine, because I have nothing to hide"– the point isn't damage, it's that 2FA is a proven security benefit that is _monumentally_ more secure than password-only auth, and Stack Exchange should seek to provide its users with the most security within its means. 2FA should be standard, period. Outsourcing to the 3rd-party providers isn't good enough.

Comment: No one is disputing that 2FA is a good thing, @zcoop98 .what many of *are* disputing is that a lack of 2FA isn't a reason for a post that is "important" to not be posted; "important" posts don't exist and posts are susceptible to damage by other users, not just the OP's. That the OP's account does or doesn't have 2FA  doesn't protect it from a malicious edit, from another user (who may or may not have had their credentials compromised).

Comment: @Larnu I completely agree that the "important post" thing is hogwash, absolutely– my comment was meant more as commentary on this issue as a whole than this specific case, where I do genuinely see opposition to implementing 2FA on posts like this (the comment above my first read that way to me). Maybe that was a little off-topic though.

Comment: @zcoop98 what mine? I didn't dispute the damage possibility, in fact I disputed disputing it. That changes nothing about the claim that the site does not support 2FA being false. It supports it by offering third party means of logging in. It is through the creation of a local account where it is missing. It would be nice if the company either drops that local account support OR adds a 2FA method and does not leave it hanging in the middle, but that gives no right to make things look worse than they are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on how you authenticate to Stack Overflow, honestly. Most people use either Google, Facebook or GitHub authentication, and all three of those platforms support 2FA.  Stack Overflow's doesn't, sure, but I don't see that as a major...issue.  If using a Stack Overflow account doesn't meet your security requirements, you have three different options to choose from there, and again - they all offer 2FA.

Most people tend to use OAuth with their favorite service of choice and let that handle the 2FA.  It's a bit of a pain to deal with about twenty different sites' 2FA codes all at once, y'know.

Comment: "*Most people use either Google, Facebook or GitHub authentication*" => Source...? Stats...?

Comment: I'd be much happier if we just got rid of all malicious people, and good-intentioned people who regardless perform malicious acts, and the need for authentication at the same time. It would be a paradise for the 2-3 people left.

Comment: @user4581301 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3514.txt problem solved.

Comment: Seems like it would be pretty *boring* for those 2-3 people left, @user4581301. And, thus, I doubt even they would last long.

Comment: [Not if they don't break their glasses.](https://twilightzone.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Enough_at_Last)